# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6: collapsed two divs side by side are stacked when expanded

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm experimenting with Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 for a non-critical project and came across some odd behaviour. Collapsed divs that should be displayed side-by-side are stacked when they are expanded.

Here are the exact steps to reproduce the problem (see full working example below):

1. Create a `col-12` div containing two `col-6` divs. As with the pink and yellow divs in my example, the two narrow divs will sit side by side.
2. Add a link above the divs and set it up to `collapse` the `col-12` div (like the `Expand` link in the example)
3. When you expand the divs, you'll note that the two `col-6` divs are displayed side by side for a split second and then suddenly end up stacked one on top of the other.

I realise this is probably just a bug that will be fixed when Bootstrap 4 gets nearer the final version, but I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion to fix this in the meantime.

I did try various permutations of overriding the CSS in my browser development tools but I can't see what style setting is making the right-hand div drop under the left one like that, and the slight delay makes me think maybe it's a JavaScript problem instead. Or maybe it's my crummy HTML!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="row col-12">
      <!-- Title and authors -->
      <h4 class="col">
        <a href="#details" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <span>Expand</span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="details" class="row collapse" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="col col-6" style="background-color: lightblue;">
        <h3>Text on the left</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, iusto fuisset ea pri.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-6" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
        <h3>Text on the right</h3>
        <p>Cu sed latine tacimates maluisset, nibh.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="col col-6" style="background-color: lightpink;">
        <h3>Exact same as collapsed area above but no collapse</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, iusto fuisset ea pri.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-6" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
        <h3>Text on the bottom right</h3>
        <p>Cu sed latine tacimates maluisset, nibh.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue has been opened for this on GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22600

Meanwhile, a workaround is to use..

```
.row.collapse.show {
    display: flex;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/jjHvwkYalf

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for the fix and for linking to the issue, which I couldn't find given the description.